Why does dottrace measure time in MB?
I started to use dotTrace, try to profile my my project and see the folowing picture:

Can somebody tell me why I see Total time in MB? What does it mean?
I have selected the following Events:

How to understand Time in megabytes? Does not make any sence. I tried Jet brains Documentation but did not find anything about it.
